# is it possible to simplify infinity minus infinity limit situations with l'hospital's rule?

Tags: limits

I know almost all intermediate forms can be simplified with this rule but I do not know a general way to simplify infinity plus or minus infinity situations with this rule, how can I do this?

Comment: Usually finding a common denominator works to put the difference in ratio form. I'm not sure if this can be proven to work for any functions.

Comment: $e^{f-g}=\frac{e^f}{e^g}$. Not that I see how that will typically help, but it does change $\infty-\infty$ to $\infty/\infty$.

Comment: You could also write $\displaystyle f-g=f\left(1-\frac{g}{f}\right)$. Then doing L'Hospital on $\frac{g}{f}$ can solve the problem (for example if it's a number other than $1$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that if the limit of a function to infinity is $f(x)\pm g(x)$ where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ become infinity as $x$ approaches infinity, then $\frac{x*(f(x)\pm g(x))}{x}$ with l'hospitals rule is $x(f'(x)\pm g'(x)) + f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: You can't apply L'Hopital's rule without knowing what $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x(f(x)\pm g(x))$ is. Knowing that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$ is not enough information to determine this limit.